# Should we delete the tag [uk]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[uk](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) exists, and is often used for shopping-recommendations for people from the UK. However, this tag is not saying much as is.

Do you agree it could be deleted?

Sidenote: [english-cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-cuisine) exists if people wish to tag questions relating to typical English dishes.

Comment: Obligatory "UK is not the same as England" comment.

Comment: True, but how do you use the UK as an adjective then? "United Kingdomian cuisine" is a bit... devious.

Comment: @Mien The adjectivie is "British".

Comment: I'd say the UK is not the same as GB either :)

Comment: British is the standard demonym for anyone with UK nationality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were only 5 questions with the tag. After the positive reaction here, I deleted the tag from all of them. It will disappear from the system after not having been used for some months.